# How to break a loop by a shorthand "if-else" result?

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, break, shorthand

Suppose I have got a shorthand if-else statement inside a loop as in this case :

```
for(...)
{
    a = b == c ? b : c;
    // More unnecessary code if the result was true.
}
```

And I would like to break the loop by the result of the condition:

```
for(...)
{
    a = b == c ? b break : c;
    // Now the unnecessary code is not executed.
}
```

I realize I could just type it in a full way as in this example:

```
for(...)
{
    if( b == c )
    {
        a = b;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        a = c;
    }
    // Now the unnecessary code is not executed.
}
```

But it is too long and I am trying to have every breaking condition in a single line since there are several of them.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: + it's a very ugly way of doing this. You're sure you understand basics of programming and OOP? This has nothing to do with a clean coding style.

Comment: Based on your code you could just write `a = c; if(b == c) break;`

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do anything more in a ternary operator than what it was made for... you're left with the alternative, "full" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some information on the ternary operator and it's uses:
[`?: Operator (C#)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

What you want to do is just impossible... it's not how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a shortened syntax without utilizing the ternary operator, but what you're trying to do isn't possible. You also don't need an `else` if you have a `break` statement in the `if`.

```
for (...)
{
    if (b == c) { a = b; break; }

    a = c;
    // More code if b does not equal c
}
```

Comment: Ew... I really dislike that way of formatting conditional blocks.

Comment: @anaximander I agree, but it seemed like getting it on one line was important to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For the example you've given, you could restructure it so

```
for (int i = 0; i < count && b != c; ++i)
{
    if( b != c )
    {
        // code
    }
}
a = b;
```

However, the specific thing you are trying to do (break from within a ternary) is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator (that "shorthand if-else") is only intended to evaluate one of two statements based on the boolean. It's not so much a flow-control construct like `if`; it actually returns the result of the statement it executes. You can't use it to execute code like that.

If you're ending up with a long else-if-else-if chain, consider refactoring a little. It may be possible to replace it with a `switch` block.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function for the test. If it's reused, its at least shorter than your example.

```
int a;
if(TryEqual(b, c, out a))
    break;

bool TryEqual(int x, int y, out res)
{
    if(x == y)
    {
        res = x;
        return true;
    }
    res = y;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution.

```
for (...)
{
  if ( (b == c ? (a=b) == a : (a=c) != a) ) break;
}
```

Of course the astute reader will notice that you could *always* assign `a=c` and then break if and only if `b==c` as that would be equivalent.

```
for (...)
{
  a = c; if (b==c) break;
}
```

That is about is as short and elegant as it is going to get while still keeping those pesky if-else constructs coalesced to a single lines.